# Format value result in texbox. 580 to 0.58E

Tags: c#, textbox, numbers, format, addition

how to format my result to something like that 580 to 0.58E in textbox4 here ?, i cannot find a solution.

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double c, moc, dlugosc, koszt;
        c = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
        moc = Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text);
        dlugosc = Convert.ToDouble(textBox3.Text);
        koszt= c * moc * dlugosc;
        textBox4.Text = Convert.ToString(koszt);
    }
```

Comment: 0.58E isn't a number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:
`textBox4.Text = (koszt / 1000).ToString() + "E"`
which is the simplest method.

If you want to format it as currency, you should use: `textBox4.Text = koszt.ToString("C")` or `textBox4.Text = (koszt / 1000).ToString("C")` which would add currency-specific information. (Which I assume is what you want.)

Without knowing what all of your values mean (as they are not English) I can't infer an answer any further.

Edit: See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: this is for calculating power consuption, c=price per kWh, moc=power of device in Watts, dlugosc= how long device will be connected and koszt= price to pay.

Comment: Then any of the above should work. The advantage to the "C" format specifier is that it uses your Locale to determine how to format it. Additionally, if you had other things to do with the koszt value, you should probably set it to: `koszt = (c / 1000) * moc * dlugosc;` instead, then you would use `textBox4.Text = koszt.ToString("C")`.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to replace the double to string and add "E" to the end.

```
textBox4.Text = (koszt/1000).ToString() + "E";
```

Answer (score 0):

The .NET Framework provides extensive formatting support. As you can see below:

```
double x = 1234.5678;
Console.WriteLine (x.ToString());             // 1234,5678
Console.WriteLine (x.ToString("E"));          // 1,234568E+003
Console.WriteLine (x.ToString("E2"));         // 1,23E+003
Console.WriteLine (x.ToString("e2"));         // 1,23e+003
Console.WriteLine (x.ToString("F"));          // 1234,57
Console.WriteLine (x.ToString("##.######"));  // 1234,5678
Console.WriteLine (x.ToString("00.000000"));  // 1234,567800
Console.WriteLine (x.ToString("######.##"));  // 1234,57
Console.WriteLine (x.ToString("000000.000")); // 001234,568
```

However keep in mind that "#.#" format for zero is empty string or "#.0" it is like ".0"
Hope it help!

Comment: also you can see msdn library, for example https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/kfsatb94(v=vs.110).aspx